# In 你多吃点 and 多给他点时间吧, is 多 an adjective or an adverb?

Tags: adverbs, adjectives

Usage of 多 is a little bit confusing. As I understand it's an adjective in the following example 两百多个学生, but in the below-mentioned examples is “多” an adjective or an adverb?

1）你多吃点

2）多给他点时间吧

Answer (score 3):

"多" here functions just like "more" in English. It can be an adjective or adverb

> In "多吃点",  '多' (more) is an adverb for the verb '吃'(verb). In English, "多吃点水果"  means "**eat** fruit **more**"

~

> In "吃多点" , '多点' is an adjective for an omitted object. In English, "吃多点水果" means "eat **more fruit**"

~

> In "多给他点时间吧", '多' (more) is an adverb for the verb '给' (give). In English, "多给他点时间吧" means "**give** him time **more**"

~

> In "给他多点时间吧", '多点' (more) is an adjective for the noun '时间' (time). In English, "给他多点时间吧" means "give him **more time**"

- 多; 很多/ 多点; 多些 preceding a noun is an adjective. e.g. 多糖 (a lot of sugar), 很多糖 (a lot of sugar), 多点糖 (more sugar), 多些糖 (more sugar)
- 多 preceding a verb is an adverb. e.g. 多加糖 (add sugar more)
- [verb + 多了] = [verb + often enough/ too much] ; '多了' is an adverb for the verb.  e.g. "看**多了**書" (read books **often enough**) ; "加**多了**糖" (added **too much** sugar)

> *how about 少，for example in “少吃点” is 少 an adverb here? My dictionary says 少 is only a verb and an adjective.*

少吃 = [少(adv) + 吃(v)]

少点吃 / 少吃点 = [少点(adv) + 吃 (v)]

*Actually people say 多点吃 and 少点吃 more often than 多吃点 and 少吃点*

Example:

**少**吃水果 = **not often** eat fruit (*少 is adverb for 吃*)

少点吃水果 = **eat** fruit **less**; 少吃点水果 = **eat** fruit **less** (*少点 is adverb for 吃*)

吃**少点**水果 = eat **less** fruit (*少点 is adjective for 水果*)

Comment: thank you, how about 少，for example in “少吃点” is 少 an adverb here? My dictionary says 少 is only a verb and an adjective.

Comment: @nino nino  See my edition. Basically, both 多 and 少  can be adjective or adverb, and they follow the same rule

Answer (score 1):

多 can be explained as "more" here.

> 你多吃点 -> 你吃多点
>
> 多给他点时间吧 -> 给他多点时间吧

That might be easier to understand.